# variable_get/set not working right

Tags: 6, configuration

I am using drupal 6. I have a variable in a function which I saved with variable_set. I called variable_get in a different function and it keeps giving me the default. Why wont it save the variable? I know that the variable has a value because its used in sql query.

here's my set:

```
    $staff_action = $_GET['staff_action'];
$first_name = $_GET['first_name'];
variable_set('first_name', $first_name);
$last_name = $_GET['last_name'];
variable_set('last_name', $last_name);
$email = $_GET['email'];
variable_set('email', $email);
drupal_set_message($email . " in first function");
```

here's my get in second function:

```
$first_name = $_GET['first_name'];
$last_name = $_GET['last_name'];
$email = variable_get('email', 'none found');
drupal_set_message($email . " in second function");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code where you are setting the value move the last line above variable_set() function

Change this code:

```
 $staff_action = $_GET['staff_action'];
$first_name = $_GET['first_name'];
variable_set('first_name', $first_name);
$last_name = $_GET['last_name'];
variable_set('last_name', $last_name);
$email = $_GET['email'];
variable_set('email', $email);
drupal_set_message($email . " in first function");
```

To this:

```
 $staff_action = $_GET['staff_action'];
$first_name = $_GET['first_name'];
variable_set('first_name', $first_name);
$last_name = $_GET['last_name'];
variable_set('last_name', $last_name);
$email = $_GET['email'];
drupal_set_message($email . " in first function");
variable_set('email', $email);
```

Then it should work.

Comment: no, that actually doesn't work.  I put that drupal_set_message in after I was already getting errors... But I just tried using the php 'global' command instead, and it still did't give me the email address! I know its there, its used in the query!

Comment: I tested it with drupal_set_message() at the end as you have it. I was not able to get the value but once I moved drupal_set_message() above the variabel_set it worked. This part of the code is working, you might have error in some other part of your code.

Comment: It should not make any difference, as `variable_set()` is not influenced from any function that is previously called, if those functions are not altering the variable passed to `variable_set()`.